# Site recognizing Python Selenium Webdriver on multiple pages

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am interested in using Selenium with Python to allow multiple bots to play poker against themselves on Pokernow (https://www.pokernow.club). You can create your own poker game and share a link for others to join. I have written a bot using Selenium that creates a game (and is player 1) and instantiated a new webdriver (with the shareable link) for a second bot to join the game. If I use the same webdriver browser (Chrome), however, the site recognizes that the p2 request is coming from the same source as p1 and assumes that p2 is p1. This behavior also occurs if done manually using the same browser, even using incognito mode.

This can be fixed by instantiating the second webdriver with Safari, however I am curious if there is a more elegant solution to allow both webdrivers to use Chrome without the site recognizing that they are requesting from the same source. I would like to have more than two players and I am running out of additional browsers to use.

Comment: Poker Now owner here. Join in our Discord server https://discord.gg/GP6ccu4 and come talk with me, I can help you and I want to hear more about your project. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably recognizes using cookies. You can try to use new instance of webdriver for each player. Every instance uses new profile, and this should make browsers independent:

```
driver1 = webdriver.Chrome() # for player 1
driver2 = webdriver.Chrome() # for player 2
```

You can also use Selenium Hub with [Docker](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/docker-selenium) and completely separate or use different browsers.